# Kernel and image for vector space $\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have matrix:
$$\pmatrix{
1  & -2\\
2       & -4\\
0 & 0\\
-1 & 2\\
}$$

I know how I can find KER and IM for vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ -> $\mathbb{R}^{<n}$ but for $\mathbb{R}^n$ -> $\mathbb{R}^{>n}$ I have no idea.

Comment: What is the procedure you know to find the kernel and image of a linear transformation $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ with $m<n$? Why doesn't it work for this case with $m>n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the image, the method does not depend on the dimensions of the domain and codomain: it is *always* spanned by the column vectors of the matrix.

Here, you have $$C_2=\begin{pmatrix} -2\\-4\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}=-2\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}=-2C_1,$$
so the image is spanned by the single vector $C_1$.

As to the kernel, all rows of $A$ are multiple of the first row, so
$$\ker A=\bigl\{(x,y)\mid x-2y=0\bigr\}.$$
It is the line of $\mathbf R^2$ generated by the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 2\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

The Image of your transformation is the column space of your matrix. Since your columns are linearly dependent, your image is the span of either column.

The kernel is the null-space. First, by the rank-nullity theorem (or rank theorem), it will have dimension $n-\dim(\text{col}(A))=2-1=1$. Solving the equation $Ax=0$ yields:

$$x=2y$$

and so a basis of the Kernel is $\{(2,1)^T\}$.